# MVc3 How to combine two views to create one large view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to combine two views one after the other.  one rendered in one div and the other rendered in the other div?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, make those views partial and then use the `Html.Partial` helper to *include* them:

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_view1")
</div>

<div>
    @Html.Partial("_view2")
</div>
```

or using editor/display templates:

```
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Bar)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You can render them as partial views (depending on what sort of markup they have .. you don't want to have multiple root html tags)

```
<div>@Html.Partial("View1")</div>

<div>@Html.Partial("View2")</div>
```